# Why Retrofit cannot encode properly query string with square brackets?

Tags: java, android, urlencode, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for my network layer in my Android app, but I have a problem with the URL encoding.

I have to call an REST API like that:

```
https://my_hostname.com/some_path?q=some_query&param[0]=value1&param[1]=value2&other_param=abcd
```

as you can see the query string is composed by some different kind of parameters, so I decided to use the `@QueryMap` annotation in the Retrofit Interface with a `Map<String, String>` where
`q, param[1], param[0], other_param` are String keys of the map

What do I expect? 
I expect the square brackets in the URL are encoded with `%5B` for `'['` and `%5D` for `'['`, but this does not happen.

Why does this happen? The square brackets should be encoded with percent encoding. Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong? I also tried the `@EncodedQueryMap` annotation with no differences.

Comment: that looks like your rest api should be expecting `params` to be an array of values

Comment: i think your rest server should not be using `[]` in variable names, but rather use that as everywhere else, as a list indicator, in which case the brackets should not need to be encoded.

Comment: Without encoding the bracket the server API doesn't work properly. I need to encode the brackets, but I would like to know how to do it with retrofit, and not manually.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Query names are never URL encoded.

The documentation for `@QueryMap` states:

> Values are URL encoded.

And for `@EncodedQueryMap`:

> Values are not URL encoded.

However, I just [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/620) to change this behavior a bit. I am adding support for encoding keys by using `@Query(value = "..", encodeName = true)` or `@QueryMap(encodeNames = true)`.

Comment: This has solved my case, I don't want to encode the query value, so I set instead @Query(value = "..", encodeValue = false)

Comment: What about post request?

Answer (score 2):

I just had to deal with `@QueryMap` encoding everything but `{}[]`. Most of the time I don't mind because I rarely send json in the query, and want to push the encoding down as low as possible in my application's stack, but recently I had to add an endpoint just like Ivan describes. My solution was to add an interceptor that does this:

```
Request originalRequest = chain.request();
HttpUrl url = originalRequest.url();
String urlFilePath = url.encodedPath();
if(url.encodedQuery() != null) {
    // Because Retrofit doesn't think "{}[]" should be encoded
    // but our API does
    String correctlyEncodedQuery = correctlyEncodeQuery(url);
    urlFilePath += "?" + correctlyEncodedQuery;
}
URL correctUrl = new URL(url.scheme(), url.host(), url.port(),
        urlFilePath);
Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
        .url(correctUrl)


private String correctlyEncodeQuery(HttpUrl url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String retVal = "";
    for(String queryKey : url.queryParameterNames()){
        if(retVal.length() > 0){
            retVal += "&";
        }
        String queryValue = url.queryParameter(queryKey);
        retVal += queryKey + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(queryValue, "utf-8");
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: If anyone was wondering this is added on `OkHttpClient.Builder()` eg. `new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }
        });`

Answer (score 1):

Try simple one
@GET 
and parameters @Query

Comment: clean & simple.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, if value contains JSONArray with JSONObject, retrofit doesn't encode brackets [ ] { }

Map contains element:

```
key = filter, 
value = [{"field":"some_field","value":"some_value","operator":"="}]
```

And @QueryMap send

```
http://my_server/api?filter=[{%22field%22:%22some_field%22,%22value%22:%22some_value%22,%22operator%22:%22%3D%22}]
```

QueryMap used there because of number params in GET request and objects in filter option.