# Encoding special chars in URL path

Tags: android, encoding, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit and I've got a problem with encoding '+' in my URL.

```
@GET(API_PATH + "/items")
Response search(@QueryMap(encodeValues = false) Map<String, String> options);
```

Option `encodeValues = false` for '+' works good, but it also 'eats' number of port in my API address. Is the any other solution to add 'plus' to URL?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129697/why-retrofit-cannot-encode-properly-query-string-with-square-brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129697/why-retrofit-cannot-encode-properly-query-string-with-square-brackets)